# How to subset data based on two conditions

Tags: r, subset, threshold

**Supopose I have a dataframe df**

```
> df
      ID Year Weight
1  Brown 1960    5.0
2  Green 1990    3.0
3 Yellow 1961    4.8
4  Green 1994    7.0
5  Green 1993    6.0
6  Brown 1964    8.0
7 Yellow 1960    4.6
```

**If I want to subset all IDs with a weight greater than or equal to 5, I will simply say:**

```
> df[df$Weight >= 5, ]
     ID Year Weight
1 Brown 1960      5
4 Green 1994      7
5 Green 1993      6
6 Brown 1964      8
```

**Unfortunately, the Green under year 1990 has been left out because the weight is less than 5. Is there a way that can retain all IDs as long as one of their weights is greater than or equal to 5?**

**Desired output**

```
> output
     ID Year Weight
1 Green 1990      3
2 Green 1993      6
3 Green 1994      7
4 Brown 1960      5
5 Brown 1964      8
```

**Many thanks!**

Comment: weight >= 5 | (ID == "Green" & year == 1990)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` here, and retain only rows per `ID` such that one member of the group has a weight of 5 or higher:

```
temp <- df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Min_Weight = max(Weight))

output <- temp[temp$Min_Weight >= 5, ]
output[order(output$ID), ]

  ID     Year Weight Min_Weight
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Brown  1960      5          8
2 Brown  1964      8          8
3 Green  1990      3          7
4 Green  1994      7          7
5 Green  1993      6          7
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("Brown", "Green", "Yellow", "Green", "Green", "Brown", "Yellow"),
                 Year=c(1960, 1990, 1961, 1994, 1993, 1964, 1960),
                 Weight=c(5.0, 3.0, 4.8, 7.0, 6.0, 8.0, 4.6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(any(Weight > 5))

#   ID     Year Weight
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Brown  1960      5
#2 Green  1990      3
#3 Green  1994      7
#4 Green  1993      6
#5 Brown  1964      8
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, .SD[any(Weight > 5)], ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting to a `data.table`:

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)

> df[ID %in% df[Weight>5, ID]]
      ID Year Weight
1: Brown 1960      5
2: Green 1990      3
3: Green 1994      7
4: Green 1993      6
5: Brown 1964      8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution with `ave()` and `subset()`

```
dfout <- subset(df, as.logical(with(df,ave(Weight, ID, FUN = function(x) any(x>=5)))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
     ID Year Weight
1 Brown 1960      5
2 Green 1990      3
4 Green 1994      7
5 Green 1993      6
6 Brown 1964      8
```

Comment: Shorter : `subset(df, ave(Weight > 5, ID, FUN = any))`